# Even semi-perfect numbers

Tags: number-theory

Considering any aliquot sum of the divisors of an even semi-perfect number must half of this number be present in the partial sum? For example, $20$ is an even semi-perfect number with divisors $1$, $2$, $4$, $5$, and $10$ where $20=10+5+4+1$ and $10\ (=\frac{20}{2})$ is present. Is it possible for an even semi-perfect number $n$ to not have $\frac{n}{2}$ in its sum?

Comment: Can we repeat any divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I interpreted Sean's question, as originally stated:

> "Does there exist an even semi-perfect number $n$ such that $n$ can be expressed as a sum of distinct proper positive integer divisors of $n$ without using $n/2$ as one of the summands?"

If so, the answer is "yes".

There are lots of such examples.

For example, if $n = 24$, simply note that

$$24 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 8$$

On the other hand, if Sean's question was intended to be interpreted as

> "Does there exist an even semi-perfect number $n$ such that $n$ cannot be expressed as a sum of distinct proper positive integer divisors of $n$ using $n/2$ as one of the summands?"

then the answer is not obvious, at least not to me.

For this version, if the answer is "yes", the smallest such $n$ will have to be greater than 10,000 (I checked).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are many counterexamples one family of them is $24n$ where $n \in\mathbb N$

Comment: How does 6 qualify?

Ok -- I guess you mean those are examples, not counterexamples.

Comment: Actually the form given above will follow the rule

Comment: @HarshKumar How did you deduce that ?

Comment: Yes, Ok -- I thought you were supplying counterexamples.

Comment: @quasi Yes those are examples

Comment: @quasi Oh no problem

Comment: @WiCK3DPOiSON actually the numbers those can be written in this form are called **PERFECT NUMBERS**

Comment: @Harsh Kumar -- the formula you suggested doesn't always produce examples satisfying the "must" part of the original question. For example, using your formula, the "must" condition  fails for $n = 4,6,8$.

Comment: For what this downvote is given

Comment: I had downvoted this when it gave examples. Now that it gives counterexamples, it is a correct answer.

Comment: Also, my previous response to Harsh Kumar, in which I claimed $n = 4,6,8$ did not satisfy his formula, was for his _previous_ (now deleted) claim -- the one where he claimed that all numbers of the form $$m = (2^{n-1})(2^n-1)$$ were even semi-perfect numbers such that _all_ representions of m as a sum of distinct positive integer divisors of m must be such that m/2 is one of the summands.